# Does migrating to a newer framework version resolve security issues

Tags: .net, security, .net-3.5, .net-4.6

I have an application written in .NET 3.5. Does migrating this application to the framework 4.6 will resolve security issues related to the framework 3.5 ?

Thanks for your answers :).

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, it is suggestable to upgrade to 4.6.
Refer: https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/08/net462-released
Note: There were some IIS,COM related issues in 4.6 as well but in the recent updates in August , MS has fixed and released them.